# shortcut icon of QAction on qtoolbar disappeared after closing the triggered dialog

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, icons, pyqt

I added a QAction to the QToolBar as a shortcut with an icon, when the icon is clicked(QAction emitts signal triggered()),an dialog will popup.The strange thing is when I close that dialog,both the icon on the QToolBar and QAction in the Qmenu are disappeared.Have anybody encountered this situation?
[image: Before clicking the first icon]

[image: After closing the QDialog triggered by the action of the first icon]

**Finally I find why.I delete a non-NULL pointer in the dialog!**

Comment: Better do the self answer

Comment: It's difficult to say without any details. Post a minimal working example if you can.